# Using a 2d array of flags effeciently

Tags: c++, graph

Suppose you are doing a BFS/DFS on a 2d grid. In this case you need to mark previously visited positions. You may use a 2d array of boolean. But when you will have lots of cases you have to clear it many times. Any better idea for using a 2d flag?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way I found is taking a 2d array of integer. At first we shall set all points to 0. Then at every case we will make the current visited[][] equal to case number. If the case number is equal to current case number then it is visited. else it is not visited. A psudocode is here:

```
int visited[max][max]//declare it as a global array so that it will initially 0
int case=current case number//suppose 1. We will increase it in each test.
check if visited[i][j]==case 
    YES: continue //this point is visited before
    NO : visited[i][j]=case and do next steps here.//not visited.
```

I would like to see better ideas.They will help me.Thanks.

Comment: This approach breaks when you iterate sufficient number of times to get case number overflow.

Comment: linear memory fill is a fast operation, use memset after each operation, also you can use bit fields to have data in compact form to save memory in case you have a lot of entries.

Comment: Cant understand. Can you explain when it breaks ? @Valeri Atamaniouk

Comment: memset will cost some time surely. I used this method and also in another code I did same task with memset. The time difference was significant on large limit, like max= 1000.

Comment: Depending on the scenario, the case can be executed over 2^32 times (so, that the case # overflows). In which case, visited table might have entries left from one of the previous iterations, and the logic gets broken. If you know for sure, the number of iterations is less, then there are no issues.

Comment: I think you misunderstood something. we will increase case at the place we ran a memset(this means before calling a bfs/dfs). if the case number exceeds 20^32 then the code will surely get TLE(time limit exceed), No matter you use memset of this.